# Prove that if a vector field $v: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is conservative, then it is a gradient field

Tags: vector-analysis

I need to prove the following statement:

> If $\vec{v}$ is a conservative vector field $\vec{v}: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, then it is a gradient field, i.e. $\exists$ a function $f$ such that $\vec{v} =\nabla f(\vec{x})$

I've been given the hint to consider the function $$f(\vec{x}) = \int_{C_{px}} \vec{v} \cdot d\vec{r}$$

where $C_{px}$ represents a curve going from $\vec{p}\in \mathbb{R}^n$ to $\vec{x}\in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Now I have noted that since $v$ is conservative, the integral is independent of path and $f$ is thus well-defined. However, I don't know where to progress from here.

Any tips/hints will be appreciated.

Comment: The way to progress is to show that $v$ is the gradient of $f$. Either through calculus, and likely some variation on the fundamental theorem, or through a geometric argument for why $v$ shows the direction and magnitude of greatest increase in $f$ at each point.

Comment: @Arthur Hi, thank you. I have tried to consider $$\nabla f(\vec{x}) = \nabla \int_C_{px} \vec{v} \cdot d\vec{r}$$, but I have no idea to how to progress from here...

Comment: This is proven in every textbook on vector analysis. If your teacher doesn't want to do the proof in class you can still read it in the book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Claim 1:** $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ equals the $x$-component of $v$.

**Claim 2:** Similarly, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ is the $y$-component of $v$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}$ is the $z$-component. Together this makes $\nabla f=\vec v$.

Hopefully, claim 2 is easy enough to follow. I will therefore focus on claim 1.

*Proof of claim 1:* Fix a point $(x_0,y_0,z_0)\in \Bbb R^3$. We have
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\lim_{\Delta x\to 0}\frac{f(x_0+\Delta x,y_0,z_0)-f(x_0,y_0,z_0)}{\Delta x}
$$
Because $\vec v$ is conservative, we have
$$
f(x_0+\Delta x,y_0,z_0)-f(x_0,y_0,z_0)=\int_{C} \vec v(x,y,z)\cdot d\vec r
$$
Where $C$ is a curve going from $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ to $(x_0+\Delta x,y_0,z_0)$. Also, I gave arguments to $\vec v$ to help remind us that it is a vector-valued *function*.

At this point I choose to parameterize the curve $C$ as a straight line at unit speed. In that case $\vec v\cdot d\vec r$ becomes $v_xdt$, where $v_x$ is the $x$-component of $\vec v$. I would also like to define the function
$$g(a)=\int_{x_0}^{x_0+a}v_x(x_0+t,y_0,z_0)dt$$ and note that since $g(0)=0$, our algebraic manipulations have taken us to
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\lim_{\Delta x\to 0}\frac{g(\Delta x)}{\Delta x}=g'(0)
$$
All that's left is to differentiate $g$. The fundamental theorem of calculus tells us that $g'(a)=v_x(x_0+a,y_0,z_0)$, and we are finished.

Comment: But we are working in $\mathbb{R}^n$..., not just $\mathbb{R}^3$? Any ideas how to progress with the hint?

Comment: Right, I forgot that. But there is no part of my argument that hinges on the number of variables. Just change $3$ to $n$ everywhere, and change every coordinate triple into an $n$-tuple, and it still works.